# How can i fetch numbered URLs that contain zero in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

i've a problem concerning a PHP function for a Wordpress site. As of this article https://perishablepress.com/wordpress-infinite-duplicate-content/ Wordpress has a problem for infinite pagination. So i need to fix this by catching numbered URLs and redirecting them to its parent URL.

I found this code online but i've modified it just a little bit for my needs. It works as expected, but it doesn't catch URLs that contains zero and also not redirect directly to a URL with slash (if there isn't one in the fetched URL).

From my tests, it appears that PHP is not catching the URLs that contain `0` with the parameter `is_numeric` (probably because 0 is considered an `int`, but i'm not sure). I'm not familiar with PHP, so i'm sharing this with you.

For the rest, it works perfectly, catching numbered URLs and redirecting to its parent URL. Of course, i've already closed the code into a function and loaded in an hook. But i'll share only the code itself just for better clarification:

```
global $posts, $numpages;

    $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    $result = preg_match('%\/(\d)+(\/)?$%', $request_uri, $matches);

    $ordinal = $result ? intval($matches[1]) : FALSE;

    if(is_numeric($ordinal)) {

        // a numbered page was requested: validate it
        // look-ahead: initialises the global $numpages

        setup_postdata($posts[0]); // yes, hack

        $redirect_to = ($ordinal) ? '/': (($ordinal > $numpages) ? "/$numpages/" : FALSE);

        if(is_string($redirect_to)) {

            // we got us a phantom
            $redirect_url = get_option('home') . preg_replace('%'.$matches[0].'%', $redirect_to, $request_uri);

            // if page = 0 or 1, redirect permanently
            if($ordinal) {
                header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 301 Moved Permanently');
            }

            header("Location: $redirect_url");
            exit();

        }
    }
```

I'm expecting that numbered URLs, also that contains `000000` or `01234`, are also redirected to its parent source. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `000000` is a string, not a number. Strings can start with 0, numbers can't

Comment: ok thanks for the reply, so how could i modify the code to meet the 0 string in URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is_numeric() calls for values like '0000' and '0123' will return true in php and those will be parsed into 0 and 123 as you would expect via intval().

I notice that you have changed the original code in the blog post from

```
// if page = 0 or 1, redirect permanently
($ordinal < 2) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 301 Moved Permanently');
} else {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 302 Found');
}
```

to

```
// if page = 0 or 1, redirect permanently
if($ordinal) {
    header($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'] . ' 301 Moved Permanently');
}
```

The comment no longer matches the functionality, maybe because you always want that 301 functionality for your uses?

I believe your code would handle a 0000 ordinal differently because it will evaluate false in that if check.

If I'm right in understanding what you want, you could try removing that if check altogether and see if it resolves your issue. If not can you provide some full URLs that exhibit the problem?

Comment: Hi Patrick, yes it's true what you're saying. I'd like to 301 all URLs because i'm applying conditional tags to some post type so i don't need the redirect 302. And in this control, maybe there is the problem.

So do you suggest to remove if ($ordinal) { or to fake validate the control as this: if ($ordinal <= 9) {

Comment: I would just remove the `if ($ordinal` entirely

Comment: i tested it without `if ($ordinal` but no luck. If i fire for an URL like `https://www.example.com/how-to-do-that/111` is working as expected, but if i fire for `https://www.example.com/how-to-do-that/000` is ignored.

Comment: Oh wait I think there's another change you will need that I missed. Try changing this line which does a similar if ($ordinal) check:  ```$redirect_to = ($ordinal) ? '/': (($ordinal > $numpages) ? "/$numpages/" : FALSE);``` to this  ```$redirect_to = isset($ordinal) ? '/': (($ordinal > $numpages) ? "/$numpages/" : FALSE);```

Comment: yes Patrick, that had done the trick. I'll check this as the best answer, but could you also say me, if you can, how can i redirect the non-trailing slashed URL directly to the trailing slashed URL? So if i fire `https://www.example.com/how-to-do-that/111`, the output will be `https://www.example.com/how-to-do-that` and then `https://www.example.com/how-to-do-that/`. Instead if i do this `https://www.example.com/how-to-do-that/111/` the output will be `https://www.example.com/how-to-do-that/` immediately. How can i achieve this without call the rule in htaccess that force the `/`?.Thanks a lot

Comment: You could add a check after the line where `$redirect_url` is set to do so. Check I'm writing here won't correctly handle requests that have request params but maybe that's not a concern: ```if (substr($redirect_url, -1) != '/') {
  $redirect_url .= '/';
}```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working, i tried to put it after `$redirect_url = get_option('home') . preg_replace('%'.$matches[0].'%', $redirect_to, $request_uri);` but nothing changed, the control is ignored. No problem for request params in this case. Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: i opened another question, cause it's a different problem and should help other users. If you want, you could check it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55558409/php-check-in-a-function-to-redirect-a-non-trailing-slash-url-to-trailing-slash-u